# MongoDB: How to add existing object to the collection as an field by _id

Tags: mongodb, mongosh

I already add document/image/mp3 file into db by GridFS, but now i want to use this object in my collection as a value of the field. I add objects to the collection by InsertMany command in mongosh.
How I can do this?
Thank you for your patience and attention!

Sorry, I'm newbee at MongoDB.

Comment: When you insert files into GridFS, you receive IDs for those files. You can store these IDs as references in your collection documents.